# What does this mean? Could not find command "add" when running 'bundle add'

Tags: ruby, bundler

I get this error `Could not find command "add"` when I try to run something like `bundle add bcrypt_pbkdf --version "<2.0,>=1.0"`

I cannot find anything like this online. I tried `bundle install`, `bundle update`, `gem install bundler`, etc, but it didn't work

How do I fix it?

Comment: [`bundle add`](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-add.1.html) was introduced in version 1.15. Make sure you run at least that version.

Comment: So to check my version, I run `bundle version` correct?

Answer (score 1):

`bundle` doesn't have a subcommando for adding new gems. To add a new one, open the `Gemfile` and manually add your new gem into it. Like:

```
gem bcrypt_pbkdfm, "~> 1.1"
```

After that, run:

```
bundle install
```

It will read your Gemfile, will download the gems and create a new `Gemfile.lock` with the installed version.

To understand more about the specs of Gemfile visit https://bundler.io/gemfile.html

EDIT

In fact `bundle` has `bundle add` command. I've never used, but it seems to achive the same goal as the manual insert.

Comment: Since bundler 1.15, there is in fact a `bundle add` command.

Comment: I didn't know and never used. Thanks for the contribution